# What will happen is an exception is thrown while executing a throw statement

Tags: c++

I have following code snippet:

```
try
{
    if(/*something is true*/)
    {  
       throw Win32Error(msgWin32Error->GetError()); //assume msgWin32Error is NULL
    }
}
catch (Win32Error& win32Error)
{

}
```

Assuming msgWin32Error is NULL in above code snippet, when throw statement gets executed, it will have another exception in turn. What will be the behavior in such circumstance?

Thanks,
Su

Comment: You don't get an exception when you dereference a null pointer, you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please get informed (read some books) and after that, avoid exceptions.

Comment: Test it and find out?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Why "avoid exceptions"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They are too difficult to track back and a disaster in (delivered) production code, if unhandled..

Comment: @DieterLücking: Then handle them! Or, even if you don't have a top-level handler with an `assert` in it, termination due to an uncaught exception is an _observable result_, far better than forgetting to check some error code and potentially getting symptoms UB, or _worse_. Then there's the idea that you _test_ production code. As for "too difficult to track", well only if your design is awful and you never read any books!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What gives you the intention to handle an exception/error - the documentation or the return value (results) of a function?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Huh?

Answer (score 4):

There will be no C++ exception here.

You are conflating two things:

- C++ exceptions (see: `throw`, `try`, `catch`)
- Runtime errors invoked by the operating system (e.g. segmentation fault)

The latter are sometimes also confusingly called "exceptions", but you cannot catch these with C++ `catch`.

What will happen is that the dereference of `msgWin32Error` will (probably) cause the Operating System to terminate your application. Control will never even reach your `throw` instruction.

Comment: Actually, it's entirely possible to catch such runtime errors as C++ exceptions. It's been tried and generally agreed to be a poor idea as a rule, so few (if any) compilers do so by default any more, but some did at one time, and a some still can/do if you tell them you want to.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you dereference a NULL pointer, you get undefined behavior. An exception *might* be thrown (because throwing an exception is in the list of allowable behaviors if UB is invoked), but you can't count on that. However, it's easy to construct a well defined example that gets at what I think you are asking.

```
char const* foo()
{
    throw ExceptionZ();
    return "message";
}

void bar()
{
    try
    {
        throw ExceptionX(foo());
    }
    catch(ExceptionX) { ... }
    catch(ExceptionZ) { ... }
}
```

In this case, the handler for `ExceptionZ` will be entered. The throw statement in `bar` does not complete. The exception thrown from `foo()` propagates before it can.

Comment: _"but you can't count on that"_ And I know of _no_ implementation ever that will (can?!) do this. Let's not focus too much on the UB aspect!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm not focusing on it. I don't think it's an important part of the question, so I'm just doing a quick correction of a misconception before answering what is, IMO, the actual question.